# Excel formula for count numbers of decimals

Tags: excel

I need to count the numbers of decimals places of a number.

The A1 cell value is:

```
    123456.78.
```

The formula in B1 is:

```
    =LEN(MOD(A1,1))
```

The results of MOD(A1,1) is:

```
 0.78
```

I expected the LEN to be 4 (LEN(0.78)=4). 
The Excel formula calculates 17 because the forumula returns:

```
0.779999999998836
```

Should I try a different approach? For example looking for the separator char?

```
=LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)
```

Comment: I'm finding this a little confusing - you want to count the number of decimal places in the cell _value_, which is 15 (plus a 0.).  The _displayed text_ is 4 characters long (0. and 2 decimal places). If you want it to be 2 decimal places then you could use `=ROUND(A1,2)` or `=TEXT(A1,"0.00")`.  Or you could create a named range as `=GET.CELL(53,A1)` which will show the value as displayed and you can use a `LEN` function on that to return 4.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=LEN(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(",";A1)))
```

A better formula managing a non decimal entry and different decimal separators:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".";A1));LEN(A1)-FIND(".";A1);IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",";A1));LEN(A1)-FIND(",";A1)))
```

Comment: I use the modified version of the formula to check if it's a number (thanks to [link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/451631-how-to-count-the-number-of-decimal-places-in-a-cell.html) : 'IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(".",A1)),LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1),0)'.

Comment: Your formula returns an error if the number does not contains decimals.

Comment: Yep, and I add a refinement so the separator can be "," or "."

Comment: To deal with the error `=IFERROR(LEN(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(",";A1)));0)` will return 0 if there are no decimals

Answer (score 2):

I see that the Len function is causing the math function to return the incorrect value for some reason (Len(Mod(123456.78, 1)) is returning 17 not 4, whereas Len(Mod(6.78,1) correctly returns 4).

You can add the TEXT function to your formula to change it to text, with a format of "General" to preserve the decimal precision, before calculating the length: `LEN(TEXT(MOD(A1,1), "General"))`.

For those wanting to use this to calculate the number of decimal places without the leading "0.", simply subtract 2 from the result.